# Resources for training about software?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just starting fumbling into online training resources like [Lynda](https://www.lynda.com/), [ITPro.TV](https://itpro.tv/#!), and [InfiniteSkilles](http://www.infiniteskills.com) (related to O'Reily somehow).  I had never heard of most of these a few weeks ago, and I didn't think resources like these even existed (I was trying to learn via YouTube and that was miserable).  It was my understanding that you had 2 paths: a degree (which is useless and worthless), and various certifications (which are ridiculously expensive).

I thought I would post a Q&A asking about training resources and supply a few links, but I'm not sure if it would fit, or how to phrase it so that it would.  Can I make this topic fit, or does it not fit at all?

Comment: From my "canned responses": *Please note this site is about recommending **software,** not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](//opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.*

Comment: @Izzy: That would make a good answer.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul OK, done. Waiting for [25 upvotes](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) then :)

Answer (score 4):

That would be off-topic here. From my "canned responses":

> Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](/q/935/185), [code fragments](/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](//opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.

All relevant questions here on Meta are linked in that quote, be welcome to follow them up to cross-check.